# Excel Connection to Access Database - Start Up Prompt

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet setup to pull a table from a .accdb Access database file.

Following the VBA command `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` I get a prompt saying `Do you want to connect to <Database location>.accdb?`. The user has to then click `Yes` and change the access permissions to `READ` (seems to default to `Share Deny Write`).

My research has suggested that putting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the start of the code will prevent the pop-up. **Question:** Will doing this also prevent the data being accessed from the database?

The connection string, if it is of interest is:
`'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=<File Location>.accdb;Mode=Read;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False'`

Your help would be appreciated

Thanks
Caleeco

Comment: If you already have the connection string which works wouldn't it be simpler to just try it out directly?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For some reason, this pop-up doesn't not appear every time or for all users. It never pops-up for me, not sure if I have it set as a trusted file? So I can't recreate the condition to test it. It is a network file, I have a feeling if the file is locked out... the pop-up will appear (but that's a guess).

Comment: Short answer: No :)

Comment: Actually, to explain; Display Alerts = False will cause the program to select the default (already highlighted) option, which I believe is 'Yes' in this case.

Comment: @absinthe Thanks for the response! That is certainly a step in the right direction. However, if `YES` is selected, the `Data Link Properties` window then pops up as shown here: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/blogpix/oledbreadonlymode4.gif  with `Share Deny Write` selected. I need this to default to `Read`. Any ideas?